# Perfect squares in $S_i = i^2 + b \cdot i + c$

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, quadratics, perfect-powers

I need to find perfect squares ($S_i = x^2$) in sequence:
$$S_i = i^2 + b \cdot i + c$$
where all numbers are natural: $$i,b,c,x \in \Bbb{N}$$

Now I use a straightforward approach, i just iterate over $i$ and check if $S_i$ is a perfect square. Is there a faster way of doing it?

Comment: When you say that you need to find perfect squares in a sequence, you mean numerically? Or to prove the existence of such perfect squares and to find a potential formula (depending on the parameters)?

Comment: I need to find numerically. So given $b,c$ find $i$, where $S_i$ is a perfect square. Now i'm doing it by brute-force search, but probably there exists a faster way.

Comment: you do realise that $S_i = \left(i+\frac{b}{2}\right)^2 + \left(c-\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^2\right)$ is a perfect square when the second term is $0$?